# Call myself crossing guard

Tags: grammar

You are a crossing guard.

1. I call myself **a** crossing guard.
2. I call myself crossing guard.

Which is correct?

Comment: "Guard" is a noun and takes an article or other determiner.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence means that you consider yourself a crossing guard and possibly tell people that you're a crossing guard. Note that there's an implication in that sentence that you may not actually be a crossing guard, or that you may have a different title. Examples:

> Since I lost my job, I hang out on the corner and help people cross
>   the street. I call myself a crossing guard.

(The speaker is not really a crossing guard)

> My official job title is "Pedestrian Traffic Coordinator". I call
>   myself a crossing guard.

(The speaker functions as a crossing guard but is called something else.)

The second sentence means that you literally refer to yourself as "crossing guard", in the same way that someone might say "I call myself Bob."

If the intent of the sentence is to say that you're a crossing guard, just say "I am a crossing guard."

Answer (score 0):

"Guard" is a singular, countable noun and so requires an article ("a guard", "the guard"), a possessive ("his guard", etc), or the word "one" ("one guard"). (Maybe there's another option or two I'm missing, but those are the main ones.)

Adding adjectives, like "crossing" here, doesn't change this rule.

"I call myself crossing guard" is grammatically incorrect. I suppose "crossing guard" could be a proper name and so not call for an article, but in that case it should be capitalize, "I call myself Crossing Guard." And that seems a very unlikely name.